# How to display beautiful math equations in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js, katex

Is there an easy way of rendering LaTeX equations in p5.js?

I naively tried to use KaTeX by including their [auto-render starting template](https://katex.org/docs/browser.html) in the `index.html` of a p5.js editor template and then writing an "equation" like

```
text("$$\\epsilon = 0.4$$", 30, 30);
```

in the `draw()` function. This failed, see [here](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/INFPD8a3A).

Comment: I'm not sure about KaTeX,  but moste LaTeX libraries only work in HTML, which means that `createDiv("latex code here)` should work. (Again, not sure)

Comment: @Bagel03 thanks!  mcintyre from the processing forum [answered my question here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/latex-in-processing/19691/3) using a similar idea: create a HTML <p> </p> element  using the p5 `createP()` function and inserting a KaTeX-rendered string there.